# Trying to extract value from my xml with namespace c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

here i am pasting the xml from where i am trying to extract the value.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ship:ShipConfirmResponse xmlns:ship="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Ship/v1.0">
            <common:Response xmlns:common="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
                <common:ResponseStatus>
                    <common:Code>1</common:Code>
                    <common:Description>Success</common:Description>
                </common:ResponseStatus>
                <common:TransactionReference>
                    <common:CustomerContext/>
                    <common:TransactionIdentifier>werqqa</common:TransactionIdentifier>
                </common:TransactionReference>
            </common:Response>
            <ship:ShipmentResults>
                <ship:NegotiatedRateCharges>
                    <ship:TotalCharge>
                        <ship:CurrencyCode>EUR</ship:CurrencyCode>
                        <ship:MonetaryValue>15.50</ship:MonetaryValue>
                    </ship:TotalCharge>
                </ship:NegotiatedRateCharges>
            </ship:ShipmentResults>
        </ship:ShipConfirmResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i need to find `Success` word is there or not if found then i will fetch other data like currency and monetary value.

this is my code which i used to achieve my goal. i guess some where i am making the mistake for which success value is not getting extracted rather exception is fired.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(strResponse);
        XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ship", "http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Ship/v1.0");
        xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("common", "http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0");

        string strHasSuccess = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ship:ShipConfirmResponse/common:Response/common:ResponseStatus/common:Description/", xmlnsManager).ChildNodes[0].Value;

        string sCurrencyCode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ship:ShipConfirmResponse/ship:ShipmentResults/ship:NegotiatedRateCharges/ship:TotalCharge/ship:CurrencyCode/", xmlnsManager).ChildNodes[0].Value;
        string sMonetaryValue = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ship:ShipConfirmResponse/ship:ShipmentResults/ship:NegotiatedRateCharges/ship:TotalCharge/ship:MonetaryValue/", xmlnsManager).ChildNodes[0].Value;
```

this line is not working

```
string strHasSuccess = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ship:ShipConfirmResponse/common:Response/common:ResponseStatus/common:Description/", xmlnsManager).ChildNodes[0].Value;
```

please tell me where i am making the mistake. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is me, I will remove trailing `/` from the XPath, and use `InnerText` instead of `ChildNodes[0].Value` :

```
string strHasSuccess = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ship:ShipConfirmResponse/common:Response/common:ResponseStatus/common:Description", xmlnsManager)
                           .InnerText;
```

Comment: can u guide me how to check common:Description exist in xml before extracting the value?

Comment: You can simply store selectsinglenode result into a variable, then check, if the var is null means there is no such node in the xml...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to omit the '/' at the tail of your xml path, i.e.

```
string strHasSuccess = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ship:ShipConfirmResponse/common:Response/common:ResponseStatus/common:Description", xmlnsManager).ChildNodes[0].Value;
```

Comment: ok that is sorted. can u guide me how to check common:Description exist in xml before extracting the value?

Comment: @Thomas Why don't you use linq-to-xml instead of xml paths? It would be a lot easier to do things like that with linq.